# Dagger2 Android Depedency injection java

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, build, dagger-2

i'm new to dagger2.
I'm trying to create an 'ActivityComponent' which will retrieves all information from my activity (ex : context ...), and an another component in which i'm trying to inject the 'Activity component' (in the code below, it's the CheckErrorsModel class).

```
@Singleton
public class CheckErrorsModel {

private Context context;

@Inject
public CheckErrorsModel(MainActivityComponent mainActivityComponent) {
    this.context = mainActivityComponent.getContext();
}

public void test() {
    Log.d("test", "test lancé ");
}
}
```

The Interface component class :

```
  @Singleton
  @Component()
  public interface CheckErrorsModelDi {
      CheckErrorsModel getCheckErrorsModel();
      MainActivityComponent getApplicationComponent();
  }
```

And everything related to the  Application context class :

```
@Component(modules = {MainActivityModule.class})
@Singleton
public interface MainActivityComponent {
   Context getContext();
   void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
}
```

the module class :

```
@Module
public class MainActivityModule {
    private final Context context;

    public MainActivityModule(Context context) {
       this.context = context;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Context provideContext(){
        return context;
    }
}
```

But once i try to build the app :
i got some errors :

> .MainActivityComponent cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method  MainActivityComponent getApplicationComponent();

> MainActivityComponent cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
> CheckErrorsModel getCheckErrorsModel()

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because your CheckErrorsModelDi don't have any module.
And Scope (like @Singleton) should always be on Module method and the component

And  this should be a [subComponent](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=dagger%202%20subcomponent) of MainActivityComponent

Alors you inject Method seems à bit strange.

You should use à builder instead see [bindings instance](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/)